# PhoneGap desktop app going blank in specific folder

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm a beginner at Hybrid app development and PhoneGap as well. I have two folders which I use for development.

When I develop my apps inside folder 1, the PhoneGap desktop app works perfectly fine without any issues. I am able to test my app on mobile devices and use it without an issue.

When I develop my apps inside folder 2, the PhoneGap desktop app will immediately go white as soon as I begin editing my files. Once it goes white, nothing shows and I am forced to close it. When I open the app again, the same issue occurs. I've linked a screenshot here:
[Phonegap Going White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZKh.png)

My issue is that it works fine in one folder but not the other folder. Any reason why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a PhoneGap Build question. Please amend your tags.

Comment: Apologies, I will remove it